# How to import Group Membership to new user from CSV

Tags: powershell, memberof

I'm using the following command to export **'MemberOf'** to a csv file.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership <USERNAME> | Select Name | Export-CSV -path c:\path\filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The next command:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity 'existingUser' -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof |  Add-ADGroupMember -Members 'NewUser'
```

is what we use to give the new user the same permissions.

Is there a command that asks me what groups should be taken over `(fromuser / touser)` or how to import the data from the csv to the newuser?

Comment: Hey @KG. Overkamp - would you please review my answer and if it helped, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so it might me easier to find for others. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet for this.

For example, to add new user only to groups with `Admin` in their name you have to add

```
| Where-Object {$_ -like "*Admin*"}
```

before `Add-ADGroupMember`.

If you want to use CSV as your input you have to import it and expand `name`:

```
Import-CSV C:\path\to\file.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
```

Keep in mind that before asking the question it'd be appreciated to do some research and learn a bit as what you're asking is pretty much basics. [Here's one of the courses which could help you to start](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/getting-started-with-microsoft-powershell-8276).